# How to assign a network interface to a newly created VM with ARM Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azureportal

I'm getting started with ARM in our Azure tenancy...

Firstly, I created a resource group, `TEST-RG`.

I've created a Network Interface in my resource group using the Portal. Let's call it `TEST-NIC` in resource group `TEST-RG`.

I've also created a `DS2_V2` VM called `TEST-VM`, running Windows 2012 R2 and also in `TEST-RG`.

How do I associate `TEST-NIC` with `TEST-VM`? I can't see a way of doing that in the Portal, nor can I see a way in the Portal of creating a VM with no network interface, such that I can add `TEST-NIC` later.

So, I assume this can only be done in PS, but I'm not at all clear how...

Have I lost the plot? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I've been very careful - this is a running tenancy. 
I've tried looking all round the web portal, to no avail, and the cmdlets are many and complex...
Basically, I don't want to damage anything - I need to know if I've missed a trick in the portal, or if cmdlets are the only way to go on this, and if so, where to start. It's a massive area.

Comment: so what is your end goal? if you've created a vm it has a NIC already.

Comment: I thought that was in the OP? I want to keep the Network Interface TEST-NIC separate and associate it with a VM where TEST-NIC is the only network interface for that VM - I can't see how to create a VM without a network interface either (or to create one with the pre-created TEST-NIC interface).

Comment: you can only achieve that with powershell\cli\sdk, not with portal

Comment: That's what I said in the OP - it's which PS cmdlets I need that I'm lost on...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-powershell just use existing interface, don't create a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, Azure does **not** support add a NIC to an existing VM.

> can I see a way in the Portal of creating a VM with no network
>   interface, such that I can add TEST-NIC later

We **can't** create a VM without NIC, but we can use PowerShell to create a new VM with this NIC.

Here is my script to create a new VM with **existing NIC**.

```
$ResourceGroupName = "nic"
$Location = "Eastus"
$StorageName = "jasondisk321"
$StorageType = "Standard_LRS"
$VMName = "myvm"
$VMSize = "Standard_DS2_v2"
$OSDiskName = $VMName + "OSDisk"
$StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageName -Type $StorageType -Location $Location
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name jasonnic -ResourceGroupName $rgname
$nicId = $nic.Id 
$Credential = Get-Credential
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -ComputerName $VMName -Windows -Credential $Credential
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Offer "WindowsServer" -Skus "2012-R2-Datacenter" -Version "latest"
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$OSDiskUri = $StorageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $OSDiskName + ".vhd"
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $OSDiskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption FromImage
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $vm
```

Comment: Thanks for that - really appreciated - very close to what I want - If I'm after a Windows 2012 R2 image on a DS2_V2 server, would there be a substantial difference?

Comment: @Nicko I have update my answer, please check it, about windows images, we can find in this page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage

Comment: Thanks - I used that as a base, along with the exported scripts from the Azure portal for existing similar VMs to get myself there...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't deploy an ARM VM without a NIC.

If you look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.compute/v1.3.4/New-AzureRmVM?redirectedfrom=msdn) script

It has the lines

```
$Interface = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName `
            -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
            -Location $Location `
            -SubnetId $VNet.Subnets[0].Id `
            -PublicIpAddressId $PIp.Id
```

Which is later used by

```
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface `
            -VM $VirtualMachine `
            -Id $Interface.Id
```

So if you want to use an existing NIC you just need to pass the $interface.id (from Get-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface)

When you wrap those two around the rest of a VM deployment script you'll build a VM with a NIC